# Is there a way to ensure that the correct JAR file is called by the Install4J service wrapper?

Tags: install4j

We are using Install4J v9 and our application needs to run as a Windows service. When we have installed the application as a Windows service, we have the original jar file `myApp.jar` and the service wrapper `myApp.exe` (which is running our jar file as a service) in the installation directory.

How can we ensure that our jar `myApp.jar` file is called by the service wrapper `myApp.exe` and not a substituted, fraudulent jar file?

I am wondering if `jar signing` would work, but how could install4j validate this signature?

Answer (score 0):

install4j has no functionality to validate signatures of JAR files for inclusion in the classpath.

However, if an attacker can modify your JAR file, they can also modify your .exe file, so adding protection to the .exe against modification of the JAR file would not make anything safer.

Comment: Thank you Ingo for the quick reply.
Wouldn't it be worth considering attaching actions or scripts to the launcher to check the jar file against a hash code or similar before launching it? 

When the installer is created, an Ant task could be run that calculates the application's hash code and writes it to a file that is packed into the installer. 
This hash code could be read by the action/script as a launcher variable. The action code then calculates the hash code of the jar to be executed to see if it has been tampered with. If so, the launcher would not allow the jar to get started

Comment: This does not change the fact that if you can tamper with the JAR file you can tamper with the launcher and so the launcher cannot give you any guarantees that the JAR files have not been modified. You could implement this yourself and call the verification in your main method, it would not make a difference if install4j provided such a service.